# MySQL Query Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a script that requires gathering information from a few different tables, and I just want to know if there is a way to handle my situation without running multiple queries. I'm a little new to mySQL and this example would really help with future situations.

```
tbl1 = foo_id, bar_id
tbl2 = foo_id, bool, num_id
```

From tbl1 I need to grab the foo_id where the bar_id = (random number), and then with that foo_id grab the num_id from tbl2 where the bool = 1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you learned about JOINs yet? I think you should look into INNER JOINS in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that :

```
SELECT t2.num_id
FROM tbl1 t1, tbl2 t2
WHERE t1.bar_id = number
    AND t1.foo_id = t2.foo_id
    AND t2.bool = 1
```

Comment: Perfect, I get it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

you try using joins ,

```
SELECT t2.num_id
FROM tbl1 t1 INNER JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.foo_id = t2.foo_id
WHERE t1.bar_id = number
AND t2.bool = 1
```